# Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter clearByTags Tag with parameters in ZF2

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework2, zend-cache

I'm using bramstroker's [StrokerCache](https://github.com/bramstroker/zf2-fullpage-cache) Zend Framework 2 module which itself uses Zend\Cache and has the method [clearByTags()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#zend-cache-storage-adapter-methods-taggable-interface).

If I want to clear cache, th following works fine:

```php
public function fooAction()
{
    $cs = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('strokercache_service');
    var_dump($cs->clearByTags(array(
        'controller_ClientCms\Controller\Cms'           
    )));
}
```

**However, what if I want to include parameters?**

```php
    $cs->clearByTags(array(
        'controller_ClientCms\Controller\Cms,param_action:index,param_client:foo'           
    ));
```

...does **not** work.

Here is how the tag-file in the cache directory looks like:

```
strokercache_route_home/client
strokercache_controller_ClientCms\Controller\Cms
strokercache_param_action_index
strokercache_param_client_foo
```

Comment: I've not used the library although the documentation states that you can clear params from the cache using the format `param_<paramname>_<paramvalue>`, however your example shows `param_<paramname>:<paramvalue>`

Comment: Thanks, tried your hint but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answare is simple: Please use ever tag as an own array element:

```
$cs->clearByTags(array(
    'controller_ClientCms\Controller\Cms',
    'param_action_index',
    'param_client_foo',
));
```

As I don't use the module I can't test it but after a quick code review this should work. see https://github.com/bramstroker/zf2-fullpage-cache/blob/master/src/StrokerCache/Controller/CacheController.php#L41